# Python Pandas replace returns strange results

Tags: python, regex, dictionary, replace, pandas

Don't know if this is a bug or feature. Please forgive my ignorance if it is later.

I try to use `dataframe.replace` to convert a str_type column to different texts. my dataframe column contains

```
df = pds.DataFrame([['J1801457','m2409-2'],['1457','m2409-1']],columns = ['c1', 'c2'])
c1_fromto = {'1457': 'G7_1457', 'J1801457': 'G7_1457'}
c2_fromto = {'m2409-1': 'm2409', 'm2409-2': 'm2409'}
print 'Before replace\n', df
print '\nAfter replace\n', df.replace({'c1':c1_fromto, 'c2':c2_fromto})
```

I was expecting both `'1457'` and `'J1801457'` would be converted to `'G7_1457'` when execute the single line code 
`df.replace({'old': from_to}, regex = False)`. But instead, here is what I got

- From old => to (after_replace)
- `'J1801457'` => `'G7_G7_1457'`  ## ??? how the double G7 gets here ???
- `'1457'` =>  `'G7_1457'`
- 'Others' =>  'Others'

Comment: its a nested translation ! can you add your translation code ?

Comment: if you are just wanting to replace the existing values or add them y performing a lookup then you can do `df['new'] = df.map(from_to)`, however you need to post more code, input data, existing code and desired output

Comment: Thanks both, nested translation? Could you elaborate with an example? I use replace instead of map because there are more than on columns I need to convert. Here is an code example. this is a real life case that operator sometimes enter wrong code for same part. df = pds.DataFrame([['J1801457','m2409-2'],['1457','m2409-1']],columns = ['c1', 'c2'])
c1_fromto = {'1457': 'G7_1457', 'J1801457': 'G7_1457'}
c2_fromto = {'m2409-1': 'm2409', 'm2409-2': 'm2409'}
print 'Before replace\n', df
print '\nAfter replace\n', df.replace({'c1':c1_fromto, 'c2':c2_fromto})

Comment: Your code works for me, what version pandas, numpy and python are you running? I'm running pandas 0.14.1, numpy 1.8.1 python 3.3.5 64-bit

Comment: my original pandas was 0.13.x, works after upgrade to 0.14